# I keep getting "Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS breakpoints in the first function

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to write a program that keeps track of employee payroll and I can seem to properly pass parameters by reference. When executing the program, I can't get past the user input function because of a breakpoint that automatically comes up.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 5

void userinput(int *hoursworked[size], float *rate[size], char *name[size]);
float calculatepay(float *rate[size], int *hoursworked[size]);
float tax(float *grosspay[size]);
float totalpay(float *grosspay[size]);
void print(char *name[size][20], float *rate[size], int *hoursworked[size], float *grosspay[size], float sum[size], float taxespaid[size]);

int main()
{
    int hoursworked[size];
    float rate[size];
    char name[size];
    float grosspay[size];
    float taxespaid[size];
    float sum[size];

    userinput(&hoursworked[size], &rate[size], &name[size]);
    calculatepay(&rate[size], &hoursworked[size]);
    tax(&grosspay[size]);
    totalpay(&grosspay[size]);
    print(&name[size], &rate[size], &hoursworked[size], &grosspay[size],   &sum[size], &taxespaid[size]);

    return 0;
}

void userinput(int *hoursworked[size], float *rate[size], char *name[size])
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", name[i] , 20);

        printf("Enter hours worked: ");
        scanf("%d", hoursworked[i]);

        printf("Enter hourly rate: ");
        scanf("%f", rate[i]);
    }
}

float calculatepay(float *rate[size], int *hoursworked[size])
{
    float grosspay[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        grosspay[size] = *rate[size] * *hoursworked[size];
    }
    return grosspay[size];
}

float tax(float *grosspay[size])
{
    float taxespaid[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        taxespaid[size] = *grosspay[size]*0.2;
    }
    return taxespaid[size];
}

float totalpay(float *grosspay[size])
{
    float sum;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        sum = sum + *grosspay[i];
    }
    return(sum);
}

void print(char *name[size][20], float *rate[size], int *hoursworked[size], float *grosspay[size], float sum[size], float taxespaid[size])
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("Pay to: %s", name[i][20]);
        printf("Hours worked: %d", hoursworked[i]);
        printf("Hourly rate: %f", rate[i]);
        printf("Gross Pay: %f", grosspay[i]);
        printf("Taxes paid: %f", taxespaid[i]);
        printf("Net pay: %f", *grosspay[i] - taxespaid[i]);
        printf("Total paid to all employees: %f", sum[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are completely confused about how to pass arrays. Don't you have a book? It's a lot easier than you're making it. Get rid of the asterisks in the function declarations. Get rid of the ampersands in the calls. An array is passed as a pointer automatically. BTW, you should make `size` all caps: `SIZE`. That's the usual practice for defined constants.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, pointers concept is not understood for you. When you pass a array to function, you just need to pass variable. It points to address of array. So

```
userinput(variableName);
```

And function definition should be,

```
(Void)userinput( int  variableName[size])
{
          //code here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When passing an array to a function, the function automatically receives the address of the array.  So your declarations don't need a pointer to an array, just an array.  So instead of this:

```
float totalpay(float *grosspay[size]);
```

You do this:

```
float totalpay(float grosspay[size]);
```

Also, you call to this function is incorrect:

```
totalpay(&grosspay[size])
```

This does not pass in the whole array, but a pointer to one-element-past-the-end-of-the-array.  You instead want this:

```
totalpay(grosspay);
```

Similar fixes need to be made to your other functions.

`calculatepay` uses a local `grosspay` array.  You probably want to be passing in the `grosspay` array from `main` instead.  Similarly with `tax` and `taxedpaid`.  In both cases, these functions don't need to return anything.

Also in `calculatepay` and `tax`, in your `for` loops you're accessing index `size` of the arrays instead of `i`.

You `scanf` call to read the name should be:

```
scanf("%19s", name[i]);
```

This restricts the input to 19 characters plus the null terminator.  Also, since `name` is a two-dimensional array you need to specify it in the function declaration of `userinput` as `name[size][20]`.

Also in `userinput`, once you fix the parameter declarations, the `scanf` calls for `hoursworked` and `rate` need to be updated to pass in the address of the array element you're interested in:

```
printf("Enter hours worked: ");
scanf("%d", &hoursworked[i]);

printf("Enter hourly rate: ");
scanf("%f", &rate[i]);
```

In `main`, `sum` should not be an array, since it is a total of all person's pay.  You should assign it the return value of `totalpay`:

```
sum = totalpay(grosspay);
```

That should cover most of it.

Answer (score 0):

In your main you define several arrays of different data types:

```
int hoursworked[size];
float rate[size];
char name[size];
float grosspay[size];
float taxespaid[size];
float sum[size];
```

Then you pass them to your functions:

```
void userinput(int *hoursworked[size], float *rate[size], char *name[size]);
```

when you pass the variables from main to your functions they are not matching the declared type. You are trying to pass just an array of various data types from main to a function that only accepts an **array of pointers**.

you should be passing variables as such:

```
int hoursworked[size];
float rate[size];
char name[size];
float grosspay[size];
float taxespaid[size];
float sum[size];


userinput(&hoursworked, &rate, &name);
```

And declaring your functions as such:

```
void userinput(int *hoursworked, float *rate, char *name);
```

This will match your arrays from main. For further reading I would suggest: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm. After making the changes to the first function, you will need to make changes to the other functions accordingly -> this is among other things I noticed at first glance at your program. Please debug whenever possible.